# Маршрутизация при использовании openvpn

Tags: linux, openvpn

При подключении к впн скорость интернета значительно снижается. Я подключаюсь через GUI (ubuntu). Хочу сделать так что бы при подключении к впн основной трафик на компе не шел через интерфейс впн. От впн нужно несколько закрытых ресурсов. Доступ к openvpn серверу есть. Может как то подключаться по особенному нужно, или может заставить его пушить роуты? В общем хочу быстрый нэт и ресурсы за впном

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге выяснилось что при подключении через GUI ОС ставит дефолтный роут на впн интерфейс. Как это изменить я так и не понял. В итоге нужная задача достигнута запуском в терминале. Прилагаю клиентский конфиг для подключения к микроту.

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp-client
remote 1.2.3.4 1194

ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
tls-client
nobind
ping 10
ping-restart 45
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
mute-replay-warnings
verb 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
pull
auth-user-pass auth.cfg
route-method exe 
route-delay 2 
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8

route "1.2.3.1 255.255.255.255"
route "1.2.3.2 255.255.255.255"
route "1.2.3.3 255.255.255.255"
route "1.2.3.5 255.255.255.255"
route "1.2.3.6 255.255.255.255"
route  192.168.111.0 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня в клиенском конфиг файле сделано так:

```
route 172.30.0.0 255.255.0.0 192.168.10.1
```

где 172.30.0.0 255.255.0.0 - диапазон адресов, которые находятся за сетью openvpn
192.168.10.1 - шлюз в сети опенвпн.

Соответственно у вас не должно быть в конфиге

```
redirect-gateway
```

Как вариант можно сделать так (в конфиге клиента)

```
script-security 3 system
route-noexec
route-up "/sbin/ip route add ВАШАСЕТЬ via 192.168.10.1"
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Пытаюсь добавить
route 81.200.47.206 255.255.255.255 1.2.3.4 где 1.2.3.4 шлюз на сервере  ovpn и получаю ошибку Network unricheable хотя пинг и ссш на 81.. работают.

Comment: А 1.2.3.4 пингуется? На 1.2.3.4 включен нат?

Comment: пингуется. нат включен.

Comment: А вариант с route-noexec не пробовали? Что в таблице маршрутов (ip route show) при поднятии тоннеля в обоих вариантах?

Comment: External program may not be called unless '--script-security 2' or higher is enabled. See --help text or man page for detailed info.
Fri Dec 25 15:10:22 2015 WARNING: Failed running command (--route-up): external program fork failed

Comment: вот вывод ip route show после подкл к впн
default via 172.16.16.1 dev tun0  proto static 
1.2.3.4 via 192.168.101.200 dev eth0  proto static 
172.16.16.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.16.2 
192.168.101.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.101.66  metric 1 

вижу что там он дефолтом назначает сеть впн. По идее это и есть проблема.

Comment: Он принимает маршруты от сервера. Точно в клиентском конфиге присутствует route-noexec?

Comment: И он просит включить script-security 2 в конфиг.

Comment: Отключите на сервере push "redirect-gateway"

Comment: вот конфиг подключения
client
dev tun
proto tcp-client
remote 1.2.3.4 1194
ca ca.crt
cert new.crt
key new.key
tls-client
nobind
ping 10
ping-restart 45
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
mute-replay-warnings
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
pull
route-method exe
route-delay 2
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8

route-noexec
route  81.200.47.206 255.255.255.255 172.16.16.1

Comment: за место route 81.200.47.206 255.255.255.255 172.16.16.1 используйте route-up "/sbin/ip route add 81.200.47.206 via 172.16.16.1"

Comment: WARNING: External program may not be called unless '--script-security 2' or higher is enabled. See --help text or man page for detailed info.
Fri Dec 25 16:00:00 2015 WARNING: Failed running command (--route-up): external program fork failed

Comment: Забыл про маленькую мелочь "script-security 3 system" за место "script-security 2"

Comment: это клиенту или серверу?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33440/discussion-between-monoceros-and-james-maynard).